# Processing images off UI thread - clarification

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I was reading up the **Processing Bitmap's off the UI Thread** tutorial ( http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html ) and I now have a question on the `loadBitmap` method. What exactly is the **mPlaceHolderBitmap** attribute used in the AsyncDrawable constructor? I understand that it is a Bitmap, but what does actually represent ? The Bitmap tied with the original image or a user defined 'empty' Bitmap. Some help here would be most appreciated.

```
public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `mPlaceHolderBitmap` contains a placeholder bitmap. It is some default bitmap that will be displayed right after you execute `loadBitmap()` method. It will be displayed until the desired bitmap is asynchronously loaded.

You typically use placeholders when you load images from a server (e.g. user images). You use it to fill the space with something meaningful until the proper image is loaded. Also note that the proper image cannot be always loaded - in our user image example - not all users have their images defined or there can be a network problem blocking data download.